# DIPimage measure missing argument

Tags: matlab, image-processing, diplib

[image]I am trying to use DIPimage to get some measurements of each object in an image and I get this error:

```
Error using dip_measure
DIPlib Error in function dip_Measure.
DIPlib Error in function dip_ImageCheck: Data type not supported


Error in measure (line 209)
data = dip_measure(object_in,gray_in,measurementID,objectIDs,connectivity);

Error in Untitled (line 13)
msr = measure(b, [], ({'size', 'perimeter','podczeckShapes'}))
```

How can I solve it?

Code:

```
Image = rgb2gray(imread('pillsetc.png'));

BW = imbinarize(Image);
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
imshow(BW);

[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
k = 1;
b = B{k};
y  = b(:,2);
x  = b(:,1);

msr(k) = measure(BW, [], ({'size', 'perimeter','podczeckShapes'}))
sz = msr.size;
podczeckShapes = podczeckShapes;
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Second argument is expected to be an image or `[]`, so in your case I would try `BW` or `[]`

Comment: Using the code: msr = measure(BW,[], ({'size', 'perimeter','podczeckShapes'})) I get only the first object(I presume so) and I want to for a selected object for example. I updated the question

Comment: I don’t know what your image looks like, but if `BW` is a binary image where the objects are 1 and the background 0, then `measure(BW,...)` should give you the right result. You are passing a vector of coordinates where an image is expected. `msr(6).size` will give the size of the 6th object.

Comment: Ok. I updated the code, is it fine?. Now I get this error. Anyway to by pass it? 'measure' requires DSP System Toolbox.

Error in Untitled (line 13)
msr = measure(BW, [], ({'size', 'perimeter','podczeckShapes'}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is the call to `imfill`. Because the image has bright values all around the image, it is considered that there's a large object with a hole, and your actual objects are inside this hole. `imfill` fills the hole, leaving the whole image white.

Instead, I suggest the following code to remove the frame:

```matlab
Image = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmqAF.jpg'));
BW = imbinarize(Image);

BW = BW - bpropagation(false(size(BW)), BW);
```

Because we used a filter in DIPimage, the `BW` variable now contains a `dip_image` object, not a normal MATLAB array. `dip_array(BW)` extracts the normal MATLAB array that is inside. The `dip_image` object behaves differently from a MATLAB array. For example, you can display it to an interactive figure window by just typing its name:

```matlab
BW
```

Next, we apply labeling so that we know which object ID in the measurement data corresponds to which object:

```matlab
lab = label(BW);
dipshow(lab,'labels')
```

Now we can apply the measurement function. If we use `BW` as input, `label` will be called on it. Since we already have that result, let's use it directly:

```matlab
msr = measure(lab, [], {'size', 'perimeter','podczeckShapes'});
```

Let's examine results for object ID 8, which is the large square:

```matlab
sz = msr(8).size
square = msr(8).podczeckShapes(1)
triangle = msr(8).podczeckShapes(3)
```

There are other things you can do with the measurement structure, I suggest you read [the documentation](ftp://qiftp.tudelft.nl/DIPimage/latest/docs/dipimage_user_manual.pdf). For example, we can remove from it the measurement for the littlest objects, which to me look like noise:

```matlab
msr = msr(msr.size>100); % remove measurement for noise
```

Comment: Thanks. DIPimage looks very cool. As I have already a code that use BW (Matlab array) how can I convert it to BW of dip_image object without doing any changes? Does the labeling in dip_image is the same as in regionprop (detecting objects from left to right)? How can I plot a number in the centroid of each object?

Comment: @elyraz: You don't need to convert a MATLAB array to use it with DIPimage functions, they can all work equally well with MATLAB arrays as input. But they always output images as `dip_image` objects. To convert a matrix to a `dip_image` object use the `dip_image` constructor: `imgage=dip_image(array)`. To convert back use the `dip_array` function: `array=dip_array(image)`. Neither of these two functions copies data, so the conversion is cheap.

Comment: @elyraz: The order in which objects are labeled is likely different in `label` and `regionprops`. But you can put the result of `label` into `regionprops`: `lab=label(image); data=regionprops(dip_array(lab),...)`. To show label IDs on top of each object, use `displaylabelnumbers`. If you want to plot other numbers, you can copy that file and modify it. Another way to visualize numbers is `msr2obj`, which assigns the value of a property to each object pixel. Now you can use the interactive image display to look at the value of the property for each object.